# Updating QListView from aggregation thread makes the GUI freeze

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qlistview

In a simple application, I have a `Mainwindow` containing a `QListView` using a `QAbstractListModel`.

When I start the application I start a single thread using a thread worker that gets data records from an external web service, it gets 10-20 records each
Iteration.

Problem:

In the `HttpAggrigator` class that started from the thread worker in the big while loop that iterates on each returned record, I emit a signal to another class called `ViewControler`, and its job is to populate the `QListView` model.

In this part, my window just freezes until all the items are set in the listview.

I checked with the profiling tool called “*Sleepy*” and indeed, the `ViewControler` method that sets the items is causing the slow down.

The flow:

- `MainWindow` -> starts `HttpAggrigator` (in a different thread ).
- `HttpAggrigator` -> gets records -> starts to iterate them ( to fill data objects ).
- `HttpAggrigator` -> emits a signal to `ViewControler` on each record iteration to build item into `MainWindow` `QListView`.

How can I prevent the GUI freeze and slow down when adding items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you're adding item to model you cause view to repaint itself. You should agregate items into one list and insert it into model at once. You will have 1 repaint instead of n repaints

Use method like this with more than one item at a time

```
void LostModel::addItems(QList<MyItem *> items)
{
    if(items.size())
    {
        int begin = MyItemList.size();

        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), begin, begin + items.size() - 1);
        MyItemList.append(items);
        endInsertRows();
    }
}
```

Comment: well i try it with :
void ListModel::addItem(MyItem* pMyItem) {
    
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), MyItemList.size(), MyItemList.size());
    MyItemList<< pMyItem;
    endInsertRows();
}
where QList<MyItem*> MyItemList;
but it dosnt help

Comment: That's still one row at a time. Try larger chunks. How many rows do you have in total? Check if index() and data() of your model are fast. Might want to try a profiler (e.g. callgrind, if on unix) to see where the time is spent.

Comment: thanks for your replay , i did this like your example . the add to list view is mach faster , but i have a second delay each time i add
the balk of items with this method to the QListView.
how can i avoid this 1 second delay?

Comment: Well I can't tell without some profiling data. You may get delay because of synchronization of threads? What is your development platform?

Comment: im working in windows xp 32 bit , what do you mean by synchronization of threads?

Comment: I assume that aggregation thread provides somehow data to model, so it should synchronyze (lock internal data of model) when changing it